# background-position style being ignored on hover

Tags: css

I need a class to change background-position on hover. What am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
#id1 { background: url(id1.png); }
#id2 { background: url(id2.png); }
.myClass:hover { background-position: bottom; color: yellow; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="id1" class="myClass">First</div>
<div id="id2" class="myClass">Second</div>
```

Here's an example on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zkfq6/

As you can see, the text color changes to yellow, but the background-position is ignored.

Comment: The `div` elements in your fiddle probably need widths and heights... otherwise it's very hard to see the desired effect.

Comment: @BoltClock The desired effect would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L7eZB/ But I need it to be a single class that I can add and remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` shorthand property affects `background-image` *and* `background-position`, among other things. The shorthand sets a default value for position if it isn't specified, so your first two rules with IDs expand to the following:

```
#id1 { background: url(id1.png) left top /* color, attachment, etc */; }
#id2 { background: url(id2.png) left top /* color, attachment, etc */; }
```

Your first two rules are more specific than your class + pseudo-class, so their default `background-position` always takes precedence.

Since all you specify are the URLs to the background images, the simplest fix is to use `background-image` instead of `background` in your first two rules, so that `background-position` isn't implicitly set and thus won't necessarily override your third rule:

```
#id1 { background-image: url(id1.png); }
#id2 { background-image: url(id2.png); }
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Zkfq6/1)

Comment: Works perfectly. This gives me a lot more freedom knowing this method works.

Answer (score -1):

Change to the following:

```
.myClass:hover { background-position: bottom !important; color: yellow; }
```

The style defined for ID has precedence, this will give precedence to .myClass with respect to *background-position*.

Comment: Obligatory -1 for obligatory unnecessary use of `!important`.

Comment: regardless, it is another solution to keep in mind...if you wish to define other background-* properties using background instead of listing them all out...for more info about !important: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules